# Locking annotations to base map in Pisa Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

In Pisa Composer: I am creating a complex geologic map.

I created geologic base map and then added annotations (notes, arrows) in Composer.

I need to lock the annotations to the base map in Composer to be able to create different figures by changing scales & panning.

Group and lock?

I cannot find the documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create your annotations in composer. They are just graphical objects drawn on the layout, and cannot be linked to the map at all. What you need to do is use the "Text Annotation" tool in the main map canvas to create callout text which is linked to a specific map location.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the callout text box was not suitable for what I needed, nor I did not find a way to create adequate arrows (to indicate crustal rotation) in the map window. In retrospect, I see I should put the geology symbols on in Inkscape. I had been hoping there was some way to put those items on a layer that I could lock to the map. Thank you for your confirmation.